# Magento 2: How to disable Adjustment Fee field ONLY

Tags: magento2, creditmemo, refund

I want to disable only the adjustment field from the refund section

I already created a custom template called adjustments.phtml which basically it haves all the html

```
<tr>
    <td class="label"><?php /* @escapeNotVerified */ echo __('Adjustment Fee') ?><div id="adjustment_negative_adv"></div></td>
    <td>
        <input type="text"
               name="creditmemo[adjustment_negative]"
               value="<?php /* @escapeNotVerified */ echo $_source->getBaseAdjustmentFeeNegative()*1 ?>"
               class="input-text admin__control-text not-negative-amount"
               id="adjustment_negative"/>
        <script>
            require(['prototype'], function(){

            //<![CDATA[
            Validation.addAllThese([
                ['not-negative-amount', '<?php /* @escapeNotVerified */ echo __('Please enter a positive number in this field.') ?>', function(v) {
                    if(v.length)
                        return /^\s*\d+([,.]\d+)*\s*%?\s*$/.test(v);
                    else
                        return true;
                }]
            ]);

            if ($('shipping_amount')) {
                $('shipping_amount').advaiceContainer = $('shipping_amount_adv');
                unblockSubmit('shipping_amount');
            }
            if ($('adjustment_positive')) {
                $('adjustment_positive').advaiceContainer = $('adjustment_positive_adv');
                unblockSubmit('adjustment_positive');
            }
            if ($('adjustment_negative')) {
                $('adjustment_negative').advaiceContainer = $('adjustment_negative_adv');
                unblockSubmit('adjustment_negative');
            }

            function unblockSubmit(id) {
                $(id).observe('focus', function(event) {
                    if ($$('button[class="scalable update-button disabled"]').size() > 0) {
                        enableElements('submit-button');
                    }
                });
            }
            //]]>

            });
        </script>
    </td>
</tr>
```

I also already created my custom layout called saled_order_creditmemo_new.xml in which i placed the remove block code

```
<page xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
  xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:View/Layout/etc/page_configuration.xsd">
<body>
    <referenceBlock name="creditmemo_totals">
        <block class="Magento\Sales\Block\Adminhtml\Order\Creditmemo\Create\Adjustments" name="adjustments" template="order/creditmemo/create/totals/adjustments.phtml"/>
        <referenceBlock name="adjustments" remove="true"/>
    </referenceBlock>
</body>
```

The thing is it does disable three fields the ones that editable in the picture below
[image]

How can I only disable the one i want?

Comment: If the answer is useful, please accept so other may use it.

Comment: It didnt worked. It disables all three boxes again. Now you cant see the boxes

Answer (score 1):

Try this,

> vendor/magento/module-sales/view/adminhtml/templates/order/creditmemo/create/totals/adjustments.phtml

Replace this

```
<input type="text"
               name="creditmemo[adjustment_negative]"
               value="<?= /* @escapeNotVerified */ $_source->getBaseAdjustmentNegative()*1 ?>"
               class="input-text admin__control-text not-negative-amount"
               id="adjustment_negative"/>
```

with this

```
<input type="text"
               name="creditmemo[adjustment_negative]"
               value="<?= /* @escapeNotVerified */ $_source->getBaseAdjustmentNegative()*1 ?>"
               class="input-text admin__control-text not-negative-amount"
               id="adjustment_negative" disabled/>
```

In order to override phtml with your custom module

> Vendor/Module/view/adminhtml/layout/sales_order_creditmemo_new.xml

add the below code in it.

```
<page xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:View/Layout/etc/page_configuration.xsd">
<body>
    <referenceBlock name="adjustments">
        <action method="setTemplate">
            <argument name="template" xsi:type="string">Vendor_Module::adjustments.phtml</argument>
        </action>
    </referenceBlock>
</body>
```

and copy adjustments.phtml from the following path to

> vendor/magento/module-sales/view/adminhtml/templates/order/creditmemo/create/totals/adjustments.phtml

to

> Vendor/Module/view/adminhtml/templates/adjustments.phtml

Hope this helps.

Comment: Didnt work see my reply. I never saw your response and we still have the issue.